# Fibonacci Challenge Proof

Tags: combinatorics, alternative-proof, fibonacci-numbers

We call a pair of codes x and y to be a losing pair if the Fibonacci ex- pansion for one of them ends in an even number of zeros and Fibonacci expansion for the other is obtained by adding a zero to the right of the expansion for the first one. Show that given any positive integer N, there is a losing pair x and y such that x − y = N.

The following proof below is what I found. Is there another way to write it more simpler and easier to explain.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You asked about existence, but the image you linked is for uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Let $\sum_i a_i F_i$ be the F-expansion for $N$. Then
\begin{align}
N
&=\sum a_i F_i
\\&=\sum a_i (F_{i+2}-F_{i+1})
\\&=\left(\sum a_i F_{i+2}\right)-\left(\sum a_i F_{i+1}\right)
\\&=\underbrace{\left(\sum a_{i-2} F_{i}\right)}_x-\underbrace{\left(\sum a_{i-1} F_{i}\right)}_y.
\end{align}
The expressions for $x$ and $y$ are their F-expansions, and you can see that they are a losing pair.

Comment: do you have a simpler proof for this question? or can send a reference

Comment: (1) Is there any particular part of my answer you find confusing? It looks about as simple as it gets to me. (2) I do not have a reference.